# Treepanel losing selection after appending nodes. (ExtJS / Rally)

Tags: extjs, sdk, rally

I am creating a treepanel object in Ext JS which dynamically adds nodes to the tree based on child information returned from the server. The problem I'm having is that I would like to be able to select multiple objects from the tree and have that selection remain after expanding a node. Since appending nodes is effectively changing the tree, the selection is lost. Is there any way I can preserve this selection after appending the new nodes?

Comment: i don't think there is a way without custom coding the selections preservation and then re-selecting.

Answer (score 0):

you could save the nodes or ids of the nodes being selected and then reselect them after appending additional nods.